# Add-On Registration (ARD +Zip) files in SAP B1 through automation (DevOps)

Tags: sapb1

I want to know about can we do Add-On Registration (ARD + Zip) files through automation or using DevOps Tools.
If you have any method then let me know or refer to an article.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK tool for packaging lightweight add-ons can be run from the command line to produce an ARD+Zip (the same tool that can be run in GUI mode). Note however that if you have files in sub-folders, for some reason when run from the command line these don't get included in the zip (seems to be a bug).